# HTML and CSS code to Reveal Image Animation

Tags: html, css

I need an embedded code to do animation for my image as the animation on the website below

https://www.milanollc.com/

reveal image animation css

my code is below,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .image-container {
            position: relative;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .image-container img {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }

        .overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            animation-name: reveal-image;
            animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
            z-index: 2;
            transform-origin: left center;
            transform: scaleX(1);
        }

        @keyframes reveal-image {
            from {
                transform: scaleX(1);
            }
            to {
                transform: scaleX(0);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://assets.zyrosite.com/AR0exeRVKXF4KQNo/w10-YbNbRanwNRF6lPw4.png" alt="Your Image">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to adjust my code to be the animation as the website that i have mentioned

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, your question should include your code.

Comment: The feature is sourced from here [codrops-Slice Revealer](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2018/02/06/slice-revealer/).

Comment: Would u please guide me to get this code in one script as embedded code

Comment: Click the link posted by @Tedinoz. There, click the GitHub button (below the image). On the GitHub page, click the green button  ("CODE") and select "Download Zip".

Comment: I have mentioned the code that i have, i need to adjust it to be the image animation as the website https://www.milanollc.com/